# How to restrict the size of variable types like long int on a 64-bit system?

Tags: c, variables, size

So, *long int* on 32-bit system is 32 bit & on 64-bit system is 64 bit. Now, I am writing a code on 32-bit system, having taken care of no overflows. If I run the same code on 64-bit system, all my long variables will unnecessarily take twice the memory size, which is a waste. So how to restrict the variable size on 64-bit system.

For ex, I have a variable *long long int Count*. Now Count can hold max 63 bit value in my design. If I run the same code on 64-bit system, Count will be 128 bits but according to logic, the remaining 64 bits will be wasted. So, I want to make sure Count takes only 64 bit on 64 bit system too

Comment: If you want fixed width, you need `stdint.h`

Comment: You can use `int32_t` from `stdint.h` if you're using C99

Comment: @StoryTeller I am a C amateur. Can you elaborate

Comment: *So, long int on 32-bit system is 32 bit & on 64-bit system is 64 bit*. No! I use a 64 bit system and my compiler still uses 32 bits for long int.

Comment: use types with explicit size like int32_t as defined in stdint. h

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya It only depends on what libraries you are using to compile.

Comment: @KharoBangdo google "stdint.h" first hit.

Comment: @KharoBangdo C99 defines a bunch of types whith specific bit size. `int32_t` is a signed `int` guaranteed to have a size of 32 bits.

Comment: Read about [fixed width integer types in the Standard.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1)

Comment: Also, which 64 system uses 128 bit `long long` ? I am not saying it is not possible. It just doesn't seem probable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, long int on 32-bit system is 32 bit & on 64-bit system is 64 bit.

Not necessarily. They could be 64 bit. Or they could be 32 bit.

> So how to restrict the variable size on 64-bit system.

Instead of using the primitive default types in C, such as `long`, you should use `int32_t` from stdint.h. Unlike `long`, it is fully portable and has deterministic size.

Comment: *"Fully portable"* - Well, when it's defined. The standard does allow omitting those particular typedefs.

Comment: The safest route is going with the `_leastN_t` and `_fastN_t` equivalents for full portability. But those are at least the desired width, not necessarily exact.

Comment: @StoryTeller Name one compiler that doesn't. Oh that's right, no such compiler will ever exist, because unlike the standard, compilers strive to be useful in the real world. If someone was to make a compiler without stdint.h, no programmer would use that compiler. Therefore, Darwin ensures that all compilers do support stdint.h, no matter what some defect in the C11 standard says.

Comment: @DeiDei The OP seems to want exactly 32 bits.

Comment: @Lundin - (1) Mind your attitude. (2) It's not a compiler's fault if the underlying platform doesn't allow a particular type to even exist.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm just so sick of yet again having this completely useless debate about portability of stdint.h. This is clearly a defect in C11 and everyone knows it. Similarly, the standard forcing compilers to implement `int64_t` etc is also a language defect.

Comment: @Lundin - if you want to lobby the C standardisation committee to mandate two's complement signed integers (and abolish other options like one's complement) then go for it. The C standard (e.g. C99, Section 7.18.1.1) makes support of `int`N`_T` mandatory for N = 8,16,32,64 if the underlying platform supports them with a two's complement representation and no padding bit. Otherwise they are optional. There is no point in telling people off for noting that types in `stdint.h`, or the header itself, are optional, when the standard says otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The actual size of "plain" integral types is platform dependent, but you can use exact-width integral types like `int32_t` or `int64_t`. Let's elaborate a bit what the standard says about the size of integral types (cf., for example, this [online c standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

First, concerning integral types, the standard gives the compiler the freedom to consider the underlying architecture:

> 6.2.5 Types (5) ... A ‘‘plain’’ int object has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment (large
>   enough to contain any value in the range INT_MIN to INT_MAX as defined
>   in the header ).

The standard specifies just a "minimum" size for each of the five standard signed integral type, which are signed char, short int, int, long int, and long long int.

> 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types  (1) The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if
>   preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for CHAR_BIT and
>   MB_LEN_MAX, the following shall be replaced by expressions that have
>   the same type as would an expression that is an object of the
>   corresponding type converted according to the integer promotions.
>   Their implementation-defined values shall be **equal or greater in
>   magnitude (absolute value) to those shown**, with the same sign.

But the standard also defines exact-width integer types:

> 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>
> (1) The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N , no padding bits, and a
>   two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed
>   integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
>
> (2) The typedef name
>   uintN_t designates an unsigned integer type with width N and no
>   padding bits. Thus, uint24_t denotes such an unsigned integer type
>   with a width of exactly 24 bits.
>
> (3) These types are optional. However,
>   if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32,
>   or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a
>   two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding
>   typedef names.

Though stating that these types are "optional", it is also said that if the implementation provides integer types of particular size/behaviour, it *shall define corresponding typedef names* . So one could derive that a compiler may decide not to provide the base integer types with the defined widths, but if it provides, then the corresponding exact-width-types will be available as well.